# Possible to test log warnings for unit tests in PHPUnit?

Tags: phpunit

Is it possible to test for log warnings while running tests for PHPUnit? Basically I have a function that logs a warning in our log files and I was wondering if there is a way to test that in PHPUnit.

Kindly note that this is not a PHP warning and I only want to test this specific warning. The result that I get back for the function that I am writing unit tests for doesn't contain information that would allow me to test whether the warning was logged or not.

I would be much obliged if someone can direct me in the right direction for this if it's possible to do.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are after from your question, but it sounds like you may be looking for a way to mock the file system.

PHPUnit can work with [vfsstream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) to do this. The PHPUnit manual gives some [guidance](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mocking-the-filesystem) on this.